Samba Server on AD
I wonder if anyone could help please as we are on a deadline at our company to complete this. We have a Samba server on Debian 11 with an inscure share that we are attempting to secure. I have recently bound it to our Active Directory domain using Winbind. When testing the share using smbclient I get back NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED. Furthermore the Samba jouirnal logs are full of failed to convert SID to UID. Running wbinfo -u and wbinfo -g shows a list of users and groups on the domain respectively, however querying a particular users with wbinfo -i returns back failed to call [I]wbcGetpwnam: WBC_ERR_DOMAIN_NOT_FOUND[/I]. It seems this error but I have searched none of the solution I have tried on the web have worked thus far. Please not that Kerberos is set and works fetching a ticket with kinit and klist.
The smb.conf config:-
[global]

    workgroup = DOMAIN
    security = ads
    realm = DOMAIN.COM
    idmap config * : range = 10000-20000
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    idmap config DOMAIN: range = 20000-30000
    idmap config DOMAIN: backend = rid
    winbind use default domain = true
    winbind offline logon = false
    template shell = /bin/bash
    template homedir = /home/%U


  log level = 5

[share]

  comment = SHARE
  read only = no
  path = /path/to/share
  guest ok = no
  public = no
  writable = yes
  valid users = @"DOMAIN\\Domain Users"


Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

FYI:  You've tagged the question as being about a Ubuntu-Debian workflow issue; where they work on Debian sid or the unstable unreleased version of Debian which is also the seed for source code for Ubuntu (thus the collaboration) but your question doesn't seem to relate to packaging for Debian & Ubuntu at all

smbclient -L DOMAIN
